# Мультиязычность на Codeignither

Tags: php, codeigniter

Как правильно сделать мультиязычность на Codeignither.

Что сделано. Прописан маршрут  `$route['(ru|en)/(:any)'] = "$2";`

Т.е. если зайти site.com/ru или **site.com/en** показывает сайт.  Узнавать какой язык выбран буду `$this->uri->segment(1)`. Но вот, как сохранить выбранный язык. Т.е. по умолчанию мы зашли, сайт на русском. Ссылку все c ru. потом мы нажали на английски, и все ссылки должны быть с en. Как можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохраняйте текущий язык в сессии. Чтобы ссылки были с сегментом языка, оборачивайте их в base_url():

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('page/example'); ?>">Ссылка</a>
```

а в конфиге base_url указывайте, как адрес сайта + язык из сессии, например:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$_SESSION['lang'];
```